# How to fix QTGLWidget using QTimer to decrease rendering time?

Tags: qt, opengl, render, qtimer, qtopengl

I am currently using QtOpenGL for my program. My program plots dots in the 3D space. These dots could be any number between one to several thousand. I am using the function, 'glusphere', for drawing the sphere to represent each dot. 
With this, each frame is created and I need to display each frames as an animation using QTimer. This animation should be controlled by fps.For example, if fps=30, I would put t=1000/30 for QTimer's setInterval(t).Whether fps=10 or 30, I found that fps does not change my program much. 
I looked for a problem by setting fps to 0 and observed how much the rendering time takes by using setInterval(0). The following is the results:

n = number of spheres

when n=10: 28ms => about 30ms

when n=100: 87ms => about 90ms

when n=150: 137ms => about 140ms

when n=1000: 598ms => about 600ms => 0.6sec

From the results above, the rendering time of each frame linearly increases with the number of spheres. The following is a part of my code:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    setFormat(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer | QGL::DepthBuffer));
    scale=1.0;
    rot_x=0;
    rot_y=0;
    rot_z=0;
    trans_x=0;
    trans_y=0;
    trans_z=0;
    isloaded=false;
    isplayed=false;
    currentFrame=1;
    sphereNum=1;
    myTimer=new QTimer(this);
    //fps=60;
    myTimer->setInterval(0);

    //myTimer->setInterval();
    connect(myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerEvent()));
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(QColor(Qt::black));
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    //QGLFormat::setDoubleBuffer(true);
    //qDebug() << "initGL context: " << this->context();
}

void GLWidget::timerEvent()
{
    static QTime current_time, last_time;
    int elapsed_time;
    last_time=current_time;
    current_time=QTime::currentTime();
    elapsed_time=(current_time.second()*1000 + current_time.msec())-(last_time.second()*1000 + last_time.msec());
    //qDebug() << "Timer elapsed time: " << elapsed_time;
    if(isloaded && isplayed) {
        if(currentFrame<markerData.frameSize) currentFrame++;
        makeCurrent();
        updateGL();
    }
    if(currentFrame==markerData.frameSize) {
        isplayed=false;
        myTimer->stop();
        currentFrame=1;
    }
}

void GLWidget::drawSphere(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat radius)
{
    qglColor(Qt::yellow);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    gluSphere(p, radius, 10, 10);
    //gluCylinder(p, 10, 10, 10, 4, 4);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void GLWidget::drawMarkers() {
    int markerIndex;
    glPushMatrix();
    /*for(int i=0; i<markerData.rowSize; i++) {
        markerIndex=(currentFrame-1)*markerData.rowSize+i;
        //qDebug() << markerIndex;
        drawSphere(markerData.markerSet[markerIndex].x, markerData.markerSet[markerIndex].y, markerData.markerSet[markerIndex].z, 10);
    }*/
    for(int i=0; i<sphereNum; i++) {
        markerIndex=rand()%1000;
        drawSphere(markerIndex, markerIndex, markerIndex, 10);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}

void GLWidget::drawText(double x, double y, double z, QString txt)
{
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    qglColor(Qt::white);
    renderText(x, y, z, txt, QFont("Arial", 12, QFont::Bold, false) );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    static QTime current_time, last_time;
    int elapsed_time;
    float paint_fps;
    //if file data is loaded
    if(isloaded)
    {
        //calculate elapsed time drown 1 frame per second
        //elapsed time is millisecond
        last_time=current_time;
        current_time=QTime::currentTime();
        elapsed_time=(current_time.second()*1000 + current_time.msec())-(last_time.second()*1000 + last_time.msec());
        paint_fps=1000/elapsed_time;
        //qDebug() << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_time << "  fps: " << paint_fps;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-20.0f);
        glRotatef(30.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(15.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(rot_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(rot_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(rot_z, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glScalef(scale, scale, scale);
        glTranslatef(trans_x, trans_y, trans_z);

        //draw elapsed time(ms)
        glPushMatrix();
        drawText(100, -300, 100, QString::number(elapsed_time) + "ms"); 
        glPopMatrix();

        //draw 3-axis
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        qglColor(Qt::red);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(3000, 0, 0);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        qglColor(Qt::green);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, 3000, 0);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        qglColor(Qt::blue);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 3000);
        glEnd();

        //draw spheres
        p=gluNewQuadric();
        drawMarkers();
        gluDeleteQuadric(p);

        //swapBuffers
        if(doubleBuffer()) {
            swapBuffers();
            makeCurrent();
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify:

- Rendering time for each frame changes depending on the number of spheres.
- The number of spheres should not change the rendering time
- Even though it draw 1000 spheres, it spends half second
- Do you think the problem is using glusphere?
- If there is another way to draw the sphere, could it be possible to do it more than 100 fps?

Could someone please explain where the bottleneck is that is creating this slow rendering?

Comment: don't use the fixed function pipeline (glBegin/glEnd) instead look at shaders, VBOs and instanced rendering

Comment: @ratchet freak  Thank you for your comment. but I don't know how can do that. Is it reason for rendering slowly?

Comment: VBOs are faster than anything! when it have 10000 spheres, just spends 2ms on disable vSync. thanks @ratchetfreak :)

Comment: Anyway if you want to draw many graphic object fast, you can use VBO and glMapBufferARB.